# How to track intermittent issue with loading/non loading of web site in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, server

I am beginner in web development. And I am working in an ASP.Net MVC 5 application and stuck with a very weird issue.

**Issue:**

Sometimes my web site just won't load in the browser. When I run in the local dev machine, website loads properly (localhost). But in LIVE the browser will keep on loading the website but nothing would load.

**Also**

After half an hour or so, website again kicks back in and starts opening properly.

**Action I took:**

Sometimes restarting the WebSite from IIS fixes the issue, BUT NOT ALL THE TIME. Sometimes even restarting did not fix the issue.

Also, I checked the Chrome Debugger, I do not see any error there (when the website was not loading).

I know something called ELMAH exists. Or some error logging in IIS. Can some one tell me how can I track this issue, in step by step process. Why my website will keep on trying to load in browser but will never load But after some time it loads. Is it IIS issue?

KINDLY NOTE: Once it starts loding fine, `then even if I close the website and reopens it, It opens superfast like a flash`. So the hiccups comes sometimes only.

I am willing to put more details, in this question. but I am not sure what to put. as far as IIS is concerned, all I know is how to restart and stop my website. that's it.

**EDIT**

Step 1: So, I searched event viewer as a whole in windows search and found something like below.

[image]

[image]

**Edit 3**

I checked the windows log, I do not see any issue related to my web app.

Comment: Try looking at the event viewer on the live machine you are hosting the site on and check if any errors show. if that doesnt help try looking into a nuget package called mini profiler.http://miniprofiler.com/ . with this you can profile certain methods and see where in your application its taking long to respond

Comment: I added the screenshot of event viewer in edit section. What is the next step now?

Comment: Should probably post your IIS App pool settings at this point, I would also either look at implementing something like log4net or writing to the event viewer so you can start logging activities just to be sure its IIS and not your application.

Comment: @TravisActon: Sir, I am a beginner. Can you kindly guide me what exactly you mean when you say `Should probably post your IIS App pool settings at this point`

Comment: I am willing to follow the instruction and get to the bottom of it

Comment: @Unbreakable Your screenshot has no value. You need expand Windows Logs, then Application, then see if anything there is related to your issue.

Comment: @mason: I added another screenshot. I do not find anything fishy there thogh

Comment: @mason: I am willing to follow every instruction. please tell me how can i get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Your second screenshot still doesn't show anything of value. As I said, you need to expand Windows Logs, then Application. Then look through the events and see if anything there is related to your problem.. Showing us a mostly blank window doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: @mason  Ok, I expanded the windows log from left nav bar in event viewer. I do not see any errors. I see some warnings but they are not related to my web application. Already its 10 mins and my weburl is still loading. (No error).

Comment: I don't even see the server not found error and all. It is just loading. :-|

Comment: Then you should add logging throughout your applications lifecycle to see how far it gets. That will help you determine where it gets stuck.

Comment: @mason: Kindly note that in localhost ever thing works fine.

Comment: @mason: Can you give me one example link on how to log. Pardon my ignorance. I am new to all this,

Comment: @Unbreakable So? What's your point? Perhaps your server isn't configured the same.

Comment: You can write to a text file, or research a logging framework for .NET and implement it in your application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153154/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-mason).

Answer (score 0):

> I know something called ELMAH exists.

Elmah is alogging framework. With just installing the NuGet package you already have an effective error logging mechanism in place. All unhandled exceptions will be logged with all the related information. It provides a page to visualize your logs and you can configure almost everything from security, to different back-end storages.

If you need a cloud base error logger with more advanced features you can use elmah.io.
Take a look at [this post](https://csharpvault.com/effective-logging-using-elmah/) for a step by step guide on how to integrate elmah.